# am trying to import a ModuleWithProviders in my standalone component but am getting errors, is there another way of importing them

Tags: angular, typescript

### am trying to import TranslateModule.forRoot({}) in my standalone component but it is giving me the error below

> > ```
> > Type 'ModuleWithProviders<TranslateModule>' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[] | Type<any>
> > ```

#### here is my component.ts

```
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-navbar',
          templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss'],
          standalone:true,
          imports:[
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
         
            // ModuleWithProviders
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
              loader:{
                provide:TranslateLoader,
                useFactory:TranslateHttpLoader,
                deps:[HttpClient]
              }
            })
        
          ]
        })
```

Comment: Have you resolved that issue?

Comment: looks like this is by design, [angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/49462#issuecomment-1473920594)